# How do I add values to a nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have a list

```
list= [['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '48', '2'], ['53', '33', '25', '2', '26', '47']]
```

that into newlist: (of first value to value:'2') in each list

```
newlist= [['1', '2'], ['1', '48'],['48', '2'], ['53', '33']['33', '25']['25', '2']]
```

but below code run on all value

```
[m[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list), 1)]
```

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: How does the output come? What's the logic behind it? It looks that some pairs are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with two for loops, one to iterate through items in list and `for` loop to iterate through `index` of `'2'` in inner list.

**Note**: It is a good practice to not to use `list` as variable name.

```
my_list= [['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '48', '2'], ['53', '33', '25', '2', '26', '47']]
new_list = [[i[j],i[j+1]] for i in my_list for j in range(i.index('2'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pair adjacent items of each sub-list by zipping with itself with an offset of 1, and then use `itertools.takewhile` to output the pairs until the first item is equal to `'2'`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
l = [['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '48', '2'], ['53', '33', '25', '2', '26', '47']]
[list(t) for s in l for t in takewhile(lambda t: t[0] != '2', zip(s, s[1:]))]
```

This returns:

```
[['1', '2'], ['1', '48'], ['48', '2'], ['53', '33'], ['33', '25'], ['25', '2']]
```